# Web scraping with python - Download Prompter getting in the way

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm scraping a wallpapers page. This page has several options for sizes for each wallpaper. My script already gives me the url of the wallpaper's size that I want. But the behavior of the page is to display a download prompt when clicked. If I just copy and paste the url in the address bar the page just refresh.

So, is there any way to bypass this prompt and get the image?

here is a sample url: http://wallpaperswide.com/download/beach_glow-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg

I'm using urlib.urlretrieve() to download, but instead of the wallpaper, I'm just downloading the entire page again.

Comment: The server is probably checking the referer header and redirecting if it thinks you linked to the image directly instead of clicked on it from the page.

Comment: so.. any suggestions?

Comment: You can manually set headers on your request object.  Try hardcoding the referer header to the url of the download page, and if it works, then come up with a way to programmatically determine the correct referer value.  Also, give the `requests` module a try.  It's much easier to use than `urllib`.